# Unable to charge at current 500mA with TP4054

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, battery-charging, lipo, tp4056

Hi I have a PCB which is operating a 5V Fan running on 500mAh 3.7v battery. The PCB uses a booster and a charging circuit. I am using TP4054 for charging module:

https://lcsc.com/product-detail/PMIC-Battery-Management_TOPPOWER-Nanjing-Extension-Microelectronics-TP4054_C32574.html

Want to charge the battery in 1 hour so I am using 1K resistor but it seems nothing is working for me because the charging time is 2 hours(tested with 560 Ohms as well). I tested and found that the charging starts at 500mA but immediately drops to 200mA and then charges continuously on it for sometime and than again drops slowly.

I am attaching a Altium design files kindly help!!

Altium files: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtZEMlINNL5Njy1TaQ9GLlR1iWO1?e=hJ4MU5

Schematics: https://1drv.ms/b/s!AtZEMlINNL5Njzf8aaUusIrz9zoV?e=vB9Hwa

Comment: What do you think might be missing from your question? Hint... it's needed to be able to understand the relevance of the resistor values you talk about. Another hint... if mind-reading was possible, then it wouldn't be needed.

Comment: vasu - Hi, From your question it isn't clear which parts are modules (i.e. bought from elsewhere) and which parts you have built from components with your own PCB design. Please edit the question & add schematics, datasheet links, photos etc. so that readers can better understand your project. What test equipment do you have (scope, DMM etc.)? What measurements have you taken? You say that you cannot charge your battery at 500 mA - so what charge current do you measure? What power source are you using to charge? What voltage & current do you measure *there*? Show your troubleshooting so far.

Comment: @SamGibson is it okay now?

Comment: @vasu - Thanks for adding details, but: "*is it okay now?*" For me, no. Several of my questions had no reply (not even e.g. "you will add the details on Monday" or whatever; just nothing). I don't have Altium here at home (same as many other readers) so the Altium files are not helpful to me (or them). It would allow more people to *perhaps* try to help you, if you added schematic *images* (jpg/png). I think I guess correctly that the resistor you mention is the TP4054 \$R_{PROG}\$ but **you must be clear and include that type of description**. So for me, too much is missing at the moment :-(